# How to loop inside a list that contains a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures

I'm trying to loop inside entities list at first, then I want to loop inside chat sources of id=1. After that id=2, then its chat sources 1,2,3. And so on.

This structure can't solve my problem.

```
entities = [
    {id: 1, "chat_sources": [1, 2, 3]},
    {id: 2, "chat_sources": [1, 2, 3]},
    {id: 3, "chat_sources": [1, 2, 3]}
]

for i in entities:
    for j in entities["chat_sources"]:
        print(j)
```

Comment: `entities` is a list. It can't be accessed with a string. You want `i["chat_sources"]` because `i` is the running variable of the loop which will get each dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
entities = [
    {id: 1, "chat_sources": [1, 2, 3]},
    {id: 2, "chat_sources": [1, 2, 3]},
    {id: 3, "chat_sources": [1, 2, 3]}
]

for entity in entities: # entity is already the item rather than its index
    for j in entity["chat_sources"]: # note it's entity, not entities
        print(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for elem in entities:
    print(*elem['chat_sources'], sep='\n')
```